# miglayout with jtable with issue

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable

I  have used miglayout in swing applicaion.I have encounted one issue like jtable cant appear in whole frame it show only left side some area. 
i want to show untill at right side end of jframe edge

My implemantaion code is below

```
package test;



import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;



public class ProductPanel2 extends JPanel {

private JLabel lblProd;
private JButton butAdd;
private JButton butRemove;
private JButton butEdit;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JTable table;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JList<String> lst_Options;
private JScrollPane scr_Data;
private JComboBox<ComboItem> cmb_Suppliers;


//Generar de inmediato
private JButton btn_NewUpdate;
private JButton btn_Delete;
private JButton btn_Copy;
private JTable tbl_Settings;
private JLabel lbl_SelectedOption;
DefaultListModel<String> modeloOpciones;
public ProductPanel2() {

    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {



    lblProd = new JLabel("Product List: ");

    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Add");
    btn_Delete = new JButton("Remove");
    lbl_SelectedOption = new JLabel("Tipo de datos");
    JLabel lbl_Opciones = new JLabel("Opciones");

    lst_Options = new JList<String>();
    modeloOpciones = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    btn_Delete = new JButton("Eliminar");

    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Nuevo");
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane();
    cmb_Suppliers = new JComboBox<ComboItem>();
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Proveedores");
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Productos");
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Partidas");
    lst_Options.setModel(modeloOpciones);

    tbl_Settings = createTable();
    tbl_Settings.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane(tbl_Settings);        

    JPanel filterPanel=new JPanel();


    setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[96px][][94.00][grow][149.00px][2px][161px]", "[16px][240px,grow][12px][29px]"));

    //add(lbl_SelectedOption, "cell 1 0,alignx left,sgx");

    add(lst_Options, "cell 0 1 1 5,grow");


    filterPanel.add(scr_Data,"wrap, sg buttons");
//  filterPanel.add(cmb_Suppliers, "");
    add(filterPanel,"span 2 3, grow, wrap");
    scr_Data.setViewportView(tbl_Settings);
    lbl_Opciones.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(lbl_Opciones, "cell 0 0,growx,aligny top");

    add(btn_Delete, "cell 6 3,alignx right,aligny bottom");
    add(btn_NewUpdate, "cell 4 3,alignx right,aligny bottom");

    refreshCombo(cmb_Suppliers);
}
private void refreshCombo(JComboBox<ComboItem> combo) {
    combo.removeAllItems();
    try {

            combo.addItem(new ComboItem("0","ashjish"));
            combo.addItem(new ComboItem("2","ashjish"));
            combo.addItem(new ComboItem("3","ashjish"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log.logToFile("refreshCombo: " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), 1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
private JTable createTable() {

    String[] columnNames = "Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4,Name 5".split(",");

    int rows = 30;
    int cols = columnNames.length;
    String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            data[i][j] = "R"+i+" C"+j;
        }
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    return table;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            ProductPanel2 pane = new ProductPanel2();
            frame.setContentPane(pane);
            frame.setSize(1000,1000);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });        

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) I do not see the point of posting screenshots when the problem is obviously with the code. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Also.. 3) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think, how you are using the `MigLayout`! Please consider reading the quickstart guide: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf

Also your variable naming needs some work, it is very unclear, which variable is for what.

In order to solve your problem, do this:

```
    tbl_Settings = createTable();
    tbl_Settings.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane(tbl_Settings);
    // I have created a new Dimension-object. Those dimensions are FIXED! You might want to put a new dimension in, that is relative to the window size.
    scr_Data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

    JPanel filterPanel=new JPanel();
```

Change this line (where you are setting absolute widths and heights for rows and columns!):

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[96px][][94.00][grow][149.00px][2px][161px]", "[16px][240px,grow][12px][29px]"));
```

To this:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

Remove all the cells you have added, because you have mixed them with other layout-parts, that are not cells:

```
add(lst_Options, "grow");
filterPanel.add(scr_Data,"wrap");
//  filterPanel.add(cmb_Suppliers, "");
add(filterPanel,"width 100%, growx, push, span, wrap");
scr_Data.setViewportView(tbl_Settings);
lbl_Opciones.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
add(lbl_Opciones, "growx,aligny top");
add(btn_Delete, "alignx right,aligny bottom");
add(btn_NewUpdate, "alignx right,aligny bottom");
```

Looks like this:

[image: Table]

---

PS: I did not know that this would work:

```
String[] columnNames = "Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4,Name 5".split(",");
```

The usual way is:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4","Name 5"};
```

I've learned something!

**EDIT:**

I've learned, that `split()` works by using regular expression, so you have to be careful, how to use it!

This will return an empty field and NOT "aaa" and "bbb":

```
"aaa.bbb".split(".");
```

---

**Update:**

I have updated my answer, this is the code in the `initComponents()`-method. I again **urge** you to read more about the `MigLayout` and stop mixing cell-components like this `add(lst_Options, "cell 0 1,grow");` with non-cell components. This is messy and hard to understand / fix. I removed those cells in my answer and added alignments for the buttons. Now everything works as expected.

```
private void initComponents() {

    lblProd = new JLabel("Product List: ");

    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Add");
    btn_Delete = new JButton("Remove");
    lbl_SelectedOption = new JLabel("Tipo de datos");
    JLabel lbl_Opciones = new JLabel("Opciones");

    lst_Options = new JList<String>();
    modeloOpciones = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    btn_Delete = new JButton("Eliminar");

    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Nuevo");
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane();
    cmb_Suppliers = new JComboBox<String>();
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Proveedores");
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Productos");
    modeloOpciones.addElement("Partidas");
    lst_Options.setModel(modeloOpciones);

    tbl_Settings = createTable();
    tbl_Settings.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane(tbl_Settings);
    tbl_Settings.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tbl_Settings.getPreferredSize());
    setLayout(new MigLayout("","[right]"));
    add(lbl_Opciones, "growx,aligny, top, wrap");
    add(lst_Options, "grow");

    add(scr_Data, "width 100%, growx, push, span, wrap");
    scr_Data.setViewportView(tbl_Settings);
    lbl_Opciones.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    btn_Delete.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    btn_NewUpdate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    add(btn_Delete, "bottom, span 2");
    add(btn_NewUpdate, "bottom");

    refreshCombo(cmb_Suppliers);
}
```

Looks like this:

[image: Updated table]

Answer (score 0):

i dont want  space  betweeb combo and jtable w[image]huich in mention at screenshot

```
package test;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;




public class ProductPanel2 extends JPanel {

private JLabel lblProd;
private JButton butAdd;
private JButton butRemove;
private JButton butEdit;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JTable table;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JList<String> lst_Options;
private JScrollPane scr_Data;
private JComboBox<ComboItem> cmb_Suppliers;


//Generar de inmediato
private JButton btn_NewUpdate;
private JButton btn_Delete;
private JButton btn_Copy;
private JTable tbl_Settings;
private JLabel lbl_SelectedOption;
private JPanel filterPanel;
private JLabel lbl_cmb_supplier;
private JButton btn_search;

public ProductPanel2() {

    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {

    lblProd = new JLabel("Product List: ");
    lbl_cmb_supplier = new JLabel("Proveedor");
    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Add");
    btn_Delete = new JButton("Remove");
    lbl_SelectedOption = new JLabel("Tipo de datos");
    JLabel lbl_Opciones = new JLabel("Opciones");
    cmb_Suppliers = new JComboBox<ComboItem>();     

    btn_Delete = new JButton("Eliminar");
    btn_search = new JButton("Search");
    btn_NewUpdate = new JButton("Nuevo");
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane();
    JComboBox<String> cmb_Suppliers = new JComboBox<String>();
    JButton btn_New = new JButton("Nuevo");
    JButton btn_Delete = new JButton("Cancelar");
    JButton btn_PDF = new JButton("Crea PDF");
    JButton btn_Send = new JButton("Envia por correo");
    tbl_Settings = createTable();
    tbl_Settings.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scr_Data = new JScrollPane(tbl_Settings);
    tbl_Settings.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tbl_Settings.getPreferredSize());
    filterPanel = new JPanel();
    /*setLayout(new MigLayout("","[right]"));
    add(lbl_Opciones, "growx,aligny, top, wrap");
    filterPanel.add(lbl_cmb_supplier, "split 2, wrap");
    filterPanel.add(cmb_Suppliers, "wrap");     
    filterPanel.add(btn_search, "grow, spany, wrap");
    add(filterPanel, "growx 5,split 2, flowy, top, sgx");
    add(scr_Data, "width 100%, growx, push, span, wrap");
    scr_Data.setViewportView(tbl_Settings);
    lbl_Opciones.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);*/


     setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[122px][129px][23px][45px][148px,grow]", "[][100px,grow][]"));
        add(lbl_Opciones, "growx, wrap");
        filterPanel.add(lbl_cmb_supplier);
        filterPanel.add(cmb_Suppliers);     
        filterPanel.add(btn_search, "grow, spany, wrap");
        add(filterPanel, "wrap");
        add(scr_Data, "width 100%, growx, push, span, wrap");


        add(btn_New);
        add(btn_PDF);
        add(btn_Send);
        add(btn_Delete);    

    refreshCombo(cmb_Suppliers);
}
private void refreshCombo(JComboBox<String> combo) {
    combo.removeAllItems();
    try {



    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log.logToFile("refreshCombo: " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), 1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
private JTable createTable() {

    String[] columnNames = "Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4,Name 5".split(",");

    int rows = 30;
    int cols = columnNames.length;
    String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            data[i][j] = "R"+i+" C"+j;
        }
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    return table;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            ProductPanel2 pane = new ProductPanel2();
            frame.setContentPane(pane);
            frame.setSize(1000,1000);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });        

}
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, which now works as specified by you. Please see the update. You still should not mix cell-components with non-cell components!

Comment: I am begginer in maglayout .what is purspose cell ,

Comment: See chapter "Using Absolute Cell Coordinates" from here: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf. With the `cell`-command you can create absolute positioned table cells (like in Microsoft Excel) and not use the "flow way" for components. But imho most of the times a flow-way layout is better, since the cell structure can become quite complex very fast. If you have small parts, you can use cells, but usually you should not. If my answer answers your question, please accept it. Else you should open new questions about specific parts of the MigLayout.

Comment: if i want to add two combo with label before jtable then what should i do

Comment: I have added my layout has broken

Comment: You should create a new question and there ask about the spaces you dont want. What you have created here is a an answer to your question. Nobody will see this as a question and therefore help you -> create a new question. :)

Comment: actullay i cant  create question because of some stackoverflow limit

Comment: can you guide me please  i couldnt understand swing miglayout