# Fix the length of java GUI Table

Tags: java, swing

I want to increase the width that the table is covering On Jpanel.

```
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setTitle("Person Table");
    jf.setSize(1100, 700);

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();jp1.setBackground(Color.green);

    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();   jp2.setBackground(Color.red);

    jp1.setSize(1100, 400);
    jp2.setSize(980, 200);

    JTable jt = new JTable(data,columnNames);   jt.setSize(900, 350); 
    jt.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            // Add table to JScrollpane
   JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt); sp.setSize(1000, 380);
   sp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
   jp1.add(sp);

    jf.add(jp1);
    jf.add(jp2);
    jf.setVisible(true);
```

This is the output

[image]

I noticed that IF I don't use Scroll pan the Column name disappears and size increases..

[image]

But I also want the column name to appear..

Comment: Are you using a LayoutManager like `MigLayout`? This usually simplifies things, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38457852/1368690

Comment: Your variable names are horrible. Makes your code very difficult to read.

Comment: JFrames default to BorderLayout so when adding components to a JFrame make sure to set a BorderLayout location e.g. BorderLayout.CENTER. The CENTER position is almost certainly where you want to put a scroll pane with a table. The reason your table headers disappear when you remove the scroll pane is because the table's JTableHeader is automatically set as the JScrollPanes column header view when a table is added to a scroll pane. With out the scroll you would need to add the JTableHeader to the layout yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the scroll pane, and replace `jp1` with it,

AKA Change:

```
jf.add(jp1);
```

to

```
jf.add(jsp);
```

This will make the table take up the whole green area*. If this isn't what you want, use nested layouts.

*Depending on the LayoutManager. In this case, `FlowLayout` is used which does not resize the component. Were you using a `GridLayout` or `BorderLayout`, the entire green area would be filled.

Comment: No problem! Mark the answer as accepted so that people know this question has been answered. Thanks

Comment: JPanel has FlowLayout as defaults in API (accepts only getPreferredSize, and isn't resizable), have to change to BorderLayout, event. GridLayout